# Calculating maximum sum of any random k elements in an array Recursively ( without any constraints)

Tags: recursion, sum, max, tail-recursion, recursive-backtracking

What would be the fastest way to find the maximum of n elements within an array. (They don't need to be consecutive)

Eg a={1 ,3, 2, 5, 0, 10}

maximum sum when n=2 will be 15

Eg if

- n was 2 then we would use two loops
- n was 3 we would use 3 loops but
  that would be O(n^3).

then for n = 4, 5 ... the solution becomes very hard to find iteratively

I thought recursion could present a solution for this so I came up with

```
long rec(ArrayList<Int> a, int i, int n) {      
        if (i > 0 && i< n) {
            return Math.max(a.get(i), rec(a, i-1, m)+ a.get(i));
        
        } else {
            return a.get(0);
        }
    }
```

called by

```
 for(int i = a.size() -1; i >=n; i--) {
             long max = rec(a,i,n);
        
}
```

But I can't seem to see a solution. Any suggestions on possible algorithms or approaches?
Thanks

Comment: 3 loops is O(3N)~O(N) not O(N³) thankfully.

Comment: sort the array first (in nlogn complexity) then take sum of n first entries ? scales and is easy to code

Comment: more complex to write but without a sort is traverse array once with a fixed size array of size n `Maxs` in which you store the largest values you encounter sorted ascending, so that if you current cell is larger than smallest value in Maxs, it is adopted. Then sum the values in the Maxs array at end of traversal.

Comment: Ahh got it. I was only thinking of a recursive way because it was a constraint in the question. I should have made myself clearer

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer from the time complexity point of view. Assuming that the input array has a size of `S` elements.

1. Solution above with the fixed "maximums" array of size `n` storing
   all the maximums.

- if the maximums in the array are sorted in place, searching with
  binary search to see if an element from the input array is present or
  should be inserted in the "maximums" array has the average complexity
  `O(log(n))`. this has to be performed for each of the elements in the
  input array so total average complexity is `O(S*log(n))`.
- if the maximums are not sorted in place, complexity will be
  `O(S*n)` since there will be a linear search in the maximums array.

2. Solution using a heap (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) into which the initial array is loaded. loading the elements in the heap is `O(S)`. popping out a maximum from the heap and re-constructing the heap is: `~O(log(S))`; doing it `n` times is `~O(n*log(S))`. so, total complexity is `O(S)+O(n*log(S))`

Let's compute the time complexity using some real sizes:

1. `S=32, n=3, O(S*log(n))~32, O(S)+O(n*log(S))~47`
2. `S=32, n=5, O(S*log(n))~64, O(S)+O(n*log(S))~57`
3. `S=32, n=8, O(S*log(n))~96, O(S)+O(n*log(S))~72`

So, IMO, for large `n` the heap solution outperforms the "maximums array" one. If we assume that the array is always stored in a heap (i.e. already pre-loaded in heap) than the heap solution is always better.